# parsing xml string in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have been trying to use code I found from other posts, to parse an xml string but when trying to get to the node elements I keep getting null values. Can someone see the error or something I am missing?

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder  db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(post));

    Document doc;
    try {

        doc = db.parse(is);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("entry");


    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the root element is null and nodelist null as well. The XML post starts with:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/
1.0/"    xmlns:service="http://activitystrea.ms/ 
service-provider"    xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" 
xmlns:gnip="http://www.post.com/schemas/2010" 
 xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:poco="http://portablecontacts.net/spec/1.0">
 <id>...
```

EDIT:

```
NodeList nodes.. //The value of the local nodes is not used
[entry: null]  
// it skips the following lines...
for(int i=0; i < nodes.getLength() - 1; i++){
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).toString());   
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: What does "keep getting null values" mean?  What variable in your code is null?

Comment: I was debugging and looking at the values for the nodelist above and root element; will post the values now.

Comment: IMO, you need to give the Node name @  root.getElementsByTagName("entry"); Instead of entry, try the actual node name.. look at this post.. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: The other thing which I m not clear is, I guess you are using DOM Parser. why do you catch SAXException ???

Comment: Thanks for the link Vikram. The catch was there from previous attempt at using SAX parsing which left me more stumped. Figured out how to get nodelist before seeing your comments & also need to figure out how to get childnodes attributes etc.

Answer (score 2):

replace  `NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName("entry");`

by   `NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();`

Comment: Thanks. I did figure that out but will credit you as I am unable to credit Vikram above whose response was helpful.